# Number only Custom directive not calling on space key

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a custom directive in **angular-1** to allow only number in a text box (no alphabets including space). 
**For example in PhoneNumber text box which should only accept Numbers.**
But my directive is accepting space. 

*Applying debug on JS, I analysed that when I press any character other than space, this directive gets fired, but on space it doesn't get called.*

My Angular Code is:

```
  campusApp.directive('numbersOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input. 
           // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
           // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined

           if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 

           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/(^0$)|[^0-9]/g, ''); 
           if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }
           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
})
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="permanentAddress.mobile" numbers-only ng-blur="saveAddress(1)" name="permanentAddress.mobile" id="permanentAddress.mobile" value="{{permanentAddress.mobile}}"/>
```

It's working fine, but when I press space at first, this directive does not get called, and accepts space. My problem is why this directive not called on Space key press?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` has an option `ng-trim`(default value is **true**), means angular will trim `space` and leads no change for ngmodel while inputing space. you can set it to false by adding `ng-trim="false"` to your directive element.